# Analytic extensions of a function defined by a series in the complex open unit disk

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

> Consider $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$.
>
> (i) Determine the dominion of $f$.
>
> (ii) Let $\Gamma=\{iy, y\in\mathbb R, |y|\geq 1\}$, and prove that $f$
>   can be prologued analytically to $\mathbb C\setminus \Gamma$.
>
> (iii) Discuss whether there exist other maximal analytic extensions to
>   domains of the Riemann sphere of the form $(\mathbb
> > C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus \Gamma'$, with $\Gamma'$ compact in $\mathbb
> > C$.

The dominion of $f$ should be the open unit disk in $\mathbb C$, in which $f$ converges absolutely, and some points on the unit circle like $1$, for Leibniz (but not $-1$: how can I check wether there are any others? *Is there some restatement of Leibniz criterion for complex series?*)

For the extension, I tried to use some form of the Schwarz simmetry principle, but, I didn't obtain anything. One could extend to $\mathbb C\setminus S^1$ by putting $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{\bar z})$ for $|z|>1$?

Thank you in advance for answers and suggestion of useful tools.

Comment: In (i), if you mean domain, it is an open connected set (i.e. the open unit disk in this case). For (ii), express the series in terms of the logarithm function. You will need the branch cut (removing $\Gamma$) to make it a single-valued function. In (iii) you can consider other branch cuts.

Comment: But you have $$f(-1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\overbrace{(-1)^{2n+1}}^{=(-1)^{2n}(-1)=-1}}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n+1}$$and this is a Leibniz series and thus converges.

Comment: If I recall correctly , the Dirichlet convergence test will show that the series  converges when $|y|=1$ and $y\ne i.$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1} = \arctan x$$

for $x\in (-1,1).$ So you have to figure that $\arctan z$ is going to be involved here. And so it is: Verify that

$$\tan z : \{-\pi/2 < \text { Re }z < \pi/2\} \to \Gamma$$

is a holomorphic bijection. (This is a nice exercise if you haven't done it before.) It follows that the inverse of $\tan z,$ which we'll call $\arctan z,$ is a biholomorphic map of $\Gamma$ onto the strip above. This is the desired analytic extension of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$ to $\Gamma.$